# Need to resize / partition

Tags: partitioning

My / partition ran out space. I don't know how to extend this partition.  Please help.  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Boot from a LiveCD (or put your drive in another computer with a partition editing tool temporarily), install + run gparted and then do it. You have to move the rest of the partitions all the way to the right to make the space available to resize the first one. It'll take a while, might want to get it started before you go to bed.

Comment: Reduce the size of the extended partition `sda2` first, there is much unallocated space in it's beginning. This will not take much time, there is no data to move, it,s done in a minute. After that you increase the size of `sda1`, you may fill up the unallocated space between `sda1` and `sda2` which you created in the first step. This will not take much time, no data to move, the whole thing will be done in a few minutes...

Comment: Why do you have a separate *non-volatile* partition for `/tmp`? I can understand having `/tmp` as a part of `/` (the default set-up) but if you go through the hassle to set up a separate partition use `tmpfs`. If you're worried your virtual memory (RAM+swap) may be to small for that, increase swap space accordingly (e. g. use the former `/tmp` partition as swap).

Comment: Thanks everyone.   I'll try to find livecd if I can get one.

Answer (score 0):

I've helped many a person resolve partitioning issues... but in looking at your gparted screenshot... oh, well... where do I start?!?

Really, truly... I'd backup any data that you have, then wipe the disk and start all over! DON'T make separate partitions for / and /boot and /home and /tmp. You've got a smallish hard disk. Just install Ubuntu by selecting `erase entire disk`. Really.